# Internet Explorer equivalent of Firefox "privacy.file_unique_origin"

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer

Sadly I can't find anything how I could solve the problem in the internet, so I ask here (And I hope I am in the correct stackexchange sub):

Where can I find the equivalent of Firefox "privacy.file_unique_origin" in Internet Explorer (on Win10)? We have a Problem with embedded pictures displaying when they are accessed over out network. When we copy that stuff on a local drive, it works.
When I changed privacy.file_unique_origin to false in Firefox, it works in FF. But because we need to test our stuff in IE too, we need a solution for this.
Anyone any idea where to find the option to turn it off?